# 2007 15" macbook pro disk full won't get past login screen

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive

I was trying to help my brother fix his computer:
A pop up that comes up at login that will tell you that your startup disk is full, he logs in and the screen gets stuck without loading any files.

I boot into EFI (or whatever you want to call it), Some reading device fails so everything is read only, but accessible. I try to plug in a external hard drive to save some items before trying to simply re-install the system, I get "SAM Multimedia: Read or Write Failed ASC=0x11 ASCQ=0x00" something similar I don't remember the exact error code I do know ASCQ was 0x0 which seemed telling. So basically I could neither find nor mount the external hard drive.

I actually this multiple times, the first time the computer crashed in EFI when I tried to open his user file.

I tried running puppy dog linux: an OS that boots from CD and runs from RAM. a device called "sda1" shows up, It had a nested file: EFI/APPLE/EXTENSIONS/Firmware.scad. I couldn't find anything else. I don't know what to do I've never had to deal with this on my mac.

Comment: Sounds like th harddrive is bad. To check run the cmd+r during start up and check the disk.

Comment: If you have use of another mac, you could try to boot in target mode > connect to the other system, and let the second system examine the drive. http://osxdaily.com/2010/04/07/how-to-boot-a-mac-in-target-disk-mode/

Comment: Start in Safe mode and delete stuff.

Comment: You could also try [deleting files in single user mode](http://superuser.com/questions/535864).

Comment: Thank you David DelMonte, I tried that, and on the millionth try, by grace of God, it worked. I managed to delete some application he wasn't using it it appeared to work. I have never encountered hardrive failure before, and he plans on getting a bigger drive to put in, but I have my doubts on the stability of the drive. Sometimes on start up (IDK how its been since recovery) it would make a strange knocking type noise and no data would read. I find it strange a full but otherwise functional hard drive would do this.